# Words with vowels in alphabetical order

Tags: java

The goal of the program is to return the words from a wordlist that have all 6 vowels (including `y`). Where the vowels are in alphabetical order. For example, an answer might be something like: Aerious (Aerious would not work though, since it does not have a `y`). Currently the program doesn't return any words. I don't think the `containsVowels` method is correct.

```java
public static void question11() {
    System.out.println("Question 11:");
    System.out.println("All words that have 6 vowels once in alphabetical order: ");
    String vowelWord = "";

    for (int i = 1; i< WordList.numWords(); i++) {
        if (containsVowels(WordList.word(i))) {       
            if (alphabetical(WordList.word(i))) {
                vowelWord = WordList.word(i);
                System.out.println(vowelWord);
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}

public static boolean alphabetical(String word) {
    int vowelPlaceA = 0;
    int vowelPlaceE = 0;
    int vowelPlaceI = 0;
    int vowelPlaceO = 0;
    int vowelPlaceU = 0;
    int vowelPlaceY = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (word.charAt(i) == 'a') {
            vowelPlaceA = i;
        }
        if (word.charAt(i) == 'e') {
             vowelPlaceE = i;
        }
        if (word.charAt(i) == 'i') {
             vowelPlaceI = i;
        }
        if (word.charAt(i) == 'o') {
             vowelPlaceO = i;
        }
        if (word.charAt(i) == 'u') {
             vowelPlaceU = i;
        }
        if (word.charAt(i) == 'y') {
             vowelPlaceY = i;
        }
        //check a alphabetical
        if(vowelPlaceA > vowelPlaceE || vowelPlaceA > vowelPlaceI || vowelPlaceA > vowelPlaceO ||
          vowelPlaceA > vowelPlaceU || vowelPlaceA > vowelPlaceY) {
             return false;
        }
        //check e alphabetical
        if(vowelPlaceE > vowelPlaceI || vowelPlaceE > vowelPlaceO ||
          vowelPlaceE > vowelPlaceU || vowelPlaceE > vowelPlaceY) {
             return false;
        }
        //i
        if(vowelPlaceI > vowelPlaceO || vowelPlaceI > vowelPlaceU || vowelPlaceI > vowelPlaceY) {
             return false;
        }
        //o
        if(vowelPlaceO > vowelPlaceU || vowelPlaceO > vowelPlaceY) {
             return false;
        }
        //u
        if(vowelPlaceU > vowelPlaceY) {
             return false;
        }    
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean containsVowels(String word) {
    String vowels = "aeiouy";
    if (word.contains(vowels)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yeah the `containsVowels` method is wrong. You're checking for the entire substring "aeiouy". Use a loop or a regex.

Comment: `contains` only returns true if the string contains that sequence of characters.

Comment: Too much complex code, you can make logic better

Comment: I know this defeats the purpose, but if you're using this in the real world with *real* words, you could probably just check it against a known list. There probably aren't very many, judging from [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18085/is-there-a-word-that-contains-all-the-vowels). I'm sure for languages besides English the same holds.

Comment: I'd say create a java String array, then use a for loop for the size of the array, and check to see if any letter is present in the word, and if so, then tell them; otherwise, tell them there is no recognition of the letters in the word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The containsVowels will only return true if the string "aeiouy" is a substring of the, word, like this:

"preaeiouy","aeiouypost","preaeiouypost"

This would be a more correct method:

```
public static boolean containsVowels(String word) {
    String vowels = "aeiouy";
    if (word == null || word.length() < vowels.length())
        return false;
    int counter = 0;
    int vowelCounter = 0;
    //Loop until the whole word has been read, or all vowels found
    while(counter<word.length() && vowelCounter < vowels.length()){
        if (word.charAt(counter) == vowels.charAt(vowelCounter)){
            vowelCounter++;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return vowelCounter == vowels.length();
}
```

Comment: NullPointerException if String is null :)

Comment: You are right, added that in, with a small check before any other checking that the word is not smaller than the vowels word to immediately return false :)

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use a regular expression in your method :

```
public static boolean containsVowels(String word) {
    return Pattern.matches(".*a.*e.*i.*o.*u.*y.*", word);
}
```

Comment: Nice, you should add .* after the "y" aswell.

Comment: Well done @Patrick. As you can see I went around the houses. +1 and feel free to downvote my answer.

Comment: And in case performance is important, then he should not use regex, its implementation is extremely slow in Java :/ But that would only matter if the words could be really big

Comment: Thank you! This question is about Java, but the regex gave me the hint I needed to use in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Use a *regular expression*

```
if (word.matches("[^aeiou]*a[^aeiou]*e[^aeiou]*i[^aeiou]*o[^aeiou]*u[^aeiou]")){
    //found one
}
```

Where `[^aeiou]*` means zero or more consonants; `^` in a regular expression means none of the stuff in `[`...`]`.

It might not be the quickest solution but it is clear; especially if you form the regular expression without hardcoding `[^aeiou]` many times as I have.

**Edit: @Patrick's regular expression is superior.**

Answer (score 2):

The logic without regex.

```
public static boolean containsVowels(String word) throws NullPointerException {
    List<String> vowels = new ArrayList<String>(
                               Arrays.asList("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"));
    String lastVowel = vowels.get(vowels.size() - 1);
    for (String c : vowels) {
        //false is returned if one vowel can't be found
        if (!word.contains(c)) {
            return false;
        }
        //true is returned once the last vowel is found (as the previous ones)
        if (c.equals(lastVowel)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    //will never go out of the loop
}
```

Comment: contains takes CharSequence as argument, not a Character.

Comment: Check for NullPointerException too, it will enchanched your code

Comment: Thanks @Plux. Replaced Character with String. Now handles CharSequence.

Comment: This would return true for any word that contains a y, and your vowels list should be strings not chars as per your implementation and use